# Why does the MLB not have awards such as MVP and Cy Young for both AL and NL together?

Tags: baseball, mlb, awards

The MLB has awards for each league, such as AL MVP and NL MVP, or AL Cy Young and NL Cy Young, but why is there no MLB MVP or MLB Cy Young, for the best out of both leagues (in a similar way to the NFL's MVP award)? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Well, the DH kind of makes a difference between the two leagues...

Answer (score 1):

Historically, the National League and American League have been separate entities where the only interleague action was the World Series. Indeed, a very long time ago, they were rival leagues. As such, they've had individual league presidents and umpires for the longest time and have only relatively recently merged those high level operations. And, of course, part of that is that each league had it's own set of awards. Unlike the umpires or league offices, there's also no desire to merge the awards (plus the union would object to half the bonuses available). This doesn't even count that the American  League has the designated hitter as a differing rule.